# How can I calculate an average speed in geolocation on mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, math, mobile, geolocation

Geolocation is very approximate, especially in buildings. 
For example, behind thick concrete walls my sensors on mobile phones show me that i'm moving up to 3 meters when the device is on the table motionless .

Which makes accurate calculations impossible in the areas which are not in the open streets.

What I think - I can make an array of 20 geopoints in 20 seconds and get average speed, but what data should I use?

If I take 19 distances from this array and divide them by `(lastTime-firstTime)` - I wouldn't get the average speed because of it can "jump" 3 meters without really moving, so the result will be totally wrong in obscured areas.

So , I can take a distance between first and last geopoints and divide it by `(lastTime-firstTime)`, but... the results will be correct only if a person move perfectly straight. If he would go 10 seconds straight and after that turned right - distance will be not the real distance he walked - the sum of two cathetuses , it would be the hypotenuse of this triangle. So, this is not the way of calculating the real speed.

What I need (I suppose) is some complex algorythm of an approximated straightened route that would be gathered into some array of `correctedDistances`and we can find a more or less true speed using them?

Like the picture shows - red is the data we get from the sensors, and black lines are the approximate real route of a person by which we can calculate more or less faithful speed.

[image]

But may be there is already a ready-made algorythm or formula made for such tasks? I don't mean google maps or any other, just a plain formula or algorythm (may be there is much simpler logic for that than I imagine)

Comment: I think you could benefit from ham sandwich theorem.

Comment: that will work fine for straight lines . How can I count cases when a person turns?

Comment: So, you want to take data and correct it without sufficient information that can help you correct it? Suppose you create such an algorithm. Case 1) as you stated and showed with a picture, inside of a building the user walks up and to the right. Your algorithm corrects from red to black. This is good for you. Case 2) User is outside of a building and makes exactly the opposite, the red path. Your algorithm will now correct the red path to the black path. This is bad for you and the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @Zéychin , yeah, you're right, but in case of dividing it into a geodata per 1 second it would be physically difficult for a person to move by the red line (unless he is really drunk) and useful distance he walked will be still black line. But... black line won't be correct in the open spaces, that's why I'm asking for maybe a better formula or algorythm